# 100 Upvotes = Bronze badge?

Tags: bug, support, status-bydesign, tags

I have the SEO badge for having 100 up votes in the SEO tag. I just noticed I have over 105 up votes in the [google tag](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/google/topusers) but do not have a badge for that. Did the number of up votes go up when the reputation requirements increased to "normal" values? Or am I missing something?

Comment: are all the votes in non-cw questions?

Comment: I just checked and none of them are. Some are from questions migrated from another SE site, though, FWIW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirements weren't fully documented.

See the tag-based badge page for a fuller explanation:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags

Comment: It *seems* I met the criteria. Total score over 100 in non-CW questions? Check. In at least 20 non-CW answers? Check.

Comment: @john are there 100+ questions tagged [google]? Look again at the sidebar requirements :)

Comment: I missed the top paragraph which contains the gotcha! Well, only two more questions to go. :)

Comment: Am I the only one who can't *read* the light-grey-on-white badge names at [Badges](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/badges)? I use Opera, but haven't changed the CSS or anything.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you've met the requirements. A total score of 100 in non-CW answers in a tag is equal to a bronze badge, and exiting beta does not have an effect on badges.

Normally, I would say to wait 24 hours, but that time period seems to already have passed, and tag badges are awarded daily, IIRC. Just in case, I suggest we wait another 24, and if nothing has changed by tomorrow, I would elevate this to `[bug]` status.